# concatenate string from divs with the same class

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, each

I have the following code.

```
function sendData(){
console.log($(".MultiFile-title").text())
}
```

And the result from multiple titles is:

file1.txtfile2.txtfile3.txt

What I need is the output to be

file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt

I believe the a FOR EACH loop would be best here but how would I write it to get the text from each div with the class name "MiltiFile-title" any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
function sendData(){
    var result = [];
    $('.MultiFile-title').each(function () {
        result.push($(this).text());
    });

    result = result.join(', ');

    console.log(result);
}
```

This creates a temporary array and loops through all the `".MultiFile-title"`s on the page, pushing each items `text` onto the array.

After it's completed looping, it `join`s the strings together using the string `", "` as glue.

Comment: You are awesome. That is exact. Thank you!

Comment: You can simplify your script by using `.map()` -> `$('.MultiFile-title').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get().join(", ")`

Comment: Is that a "simplification", or just crushing the code into a one-liner?  Sometimes that's not the best approach - especially when trying to clarify an example to a beginner.

Comment: You can't have newlines in comments - that's the only reason for the "one-liner" ;) And there is absolutely no mistery about [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Hmm the map function is very useful as well(just looked at in the jQuery API). I had never heard of it until now, but will be implementing it in the future. Thanks you as well. I am going to accept the .each() solution as the main answer. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
jQuery(".MultiFile-title").map(function(i, v){return jQuery(v).text().trim()});
```